# Intellij open project dialog - paste the folder path in MAC

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have the copied the path of the required directory to the clipboard

Now in Intellij IDE when I click file->open then it opens a dialog box, how do I paste the folder path instead of navigating manually to the folder in MAC OS?

I did not find any such option like the Finder's `Go->go to folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use "Cmd+Shift+G" shortcut to open "Go to the folder" dialog. Here is the screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmAds.jpg

Once it is opened, please use right click to paste the path from context menu.

Comment: Is there no option to do this from screen using mouse/trackpad?  want to avoid memorizing keyboard shortcut

Comment: There is no menu for that, but you can drag&drop a folder from Finder to the "Open" window, so path will be automatically filled without using keyboard.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? It doesn't seem to work on my macOS Monterey v12.3.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 20220.2 (Ultimate Edition). Instead, the key sequence appears to be associated with the editor's `Find`. Specifically, `Find Previous / Move to previous Occurrence`. Also, the `IntelliJ IDEA` | `Preferences`, `Keymap` lists no **Go to the folder** key mapping.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+G should be invoked in macos native file chooser, which is opened by IntelliJ IDEA